# NOPERM issue in Redis Connection

Tags: redis, spring-data-redis, amazon-elasticache, lettuce

```
    @Bean
    fun redisConnectionFactory(): LettuceConnectionFactory {
        val redisConfiguration = RedisClusterConfiguration().apply {
            val (host, port, username, password) = redisProperties

            addClusterNode(RedisNode(host, port))
            this.username = username
            this.password = RedisPassword.of(password)
        }
        val lettuceClientConfiguration = LettuceClientConfiguration.builder().useSsl().build()
        return LettuceConnectionFactory(redisConfiguration, lettuceClientConfiguration)
    }

    @Bean
    fun redisCommands(): RedisModulesCommands<String, String> {
        val (host, port, username, password) = redisProperties

        val redisUri = RedisURI.builder()
            .withHost(host)
            .withPort(port)
            .withAuthentication(username, password.toCharArray())
            .withSsl(true)
            .build()

        val redisModulesClient = RedisModulesClusterClient.builder(redisUri)
            .build()
        val connect = redisModulesClient.connect()
        return connect.sync()
    }

    @Bean
    fun configureRedisAction() = ConfigureRedisAction.NO_OP
```

When I apply connection with AWS ElastiCache (Set Access Stirng is `on ~* -@all +@read +@write`).

I see this error log.

`Caused by: io.lettuce.core.RedisCommandExecutionException: NOPERM this user has no permissions to run the 'cluster|nodes' command`

But I just only use redis commands `jsonGet` and `jsonSet` not `cluster|nodes`.

How can I solve this issue..? please answer about my question.

I set LettuceConnectionFactory and RedisModulesCommands<String, String>. I expected to success Connection with AWS ElastiCache.

Answer (score 4):

When configuring your client to connect to a cluster mode enabled deployment, the client uses the `CLUSTER NODES` command to the discovers all the nodes in the cluster and connect to them.

Therefore, you need to enable the `CLUSTER NODES` command for the user you want to connect with.

You can modify the user's access string using the ModifyUser action. For example, using the AWS CLI:

```
aws elasticache modify-user --region $REGION --user-id $USER_ID --access-string "on ~* -@all +@read +@write +cluster|nodes"
```

Related documentation:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/Clusters.RBAC.html
- https://redis.io/docs/management/security/acl/
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/APIReference/API_CreateUser.html